# Mostrar contenido de una base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

estoy haciendo un trabajo para la escuela, en que me piden que haga una "mini réplica" de lo que vendría siendo twitter, para que veamos el manejo de datos con php y demás.
Bien, he llegado al punto de registrar usuarios, hacer login y guardar tweets en una base de datos, pero algo tan simple como mostrar estos, pues no me sale. Veréis, tengo dos bases de datos;

> Base de datos usuarios: guardo los campos name, username, password y id, por ese orden.
>   Base de datos tweets donde guardo: id del tweet, text (contenido del tweet), date (fecha en que se publicó) y userId (id del usuario que publicó el tweet), también, en ese orden.

Bueno, pues tengo la siguiente función, que es la que se encarga de recuperar el contenido de los tweets

```
function obtenirTuits(){
    $conn = connectar();

    $sqlTweets = "SELECT * FROM tweets";
    $rowsTweets = $conn->query($sqlTweets);
    $rowsTweets = $rowsTweets -> fetch();

    if (!$rowsTweets){
        echo "<br>"."<br>"."No hi ha tuits a mostrar!";
    }else{

    }
}
```

Como podemos ver, si la variable $rowsTweets no tiene contenido, nos mostrará que no hay tweets que mostrar, en cambio, si no, debería mostrar lo siguiente:

Publicado por "usuario" a las "fecha de publicación"
Contenido del tweet

Pero no se como hacer esto, además, tendría que dar la opción de que "x" usuario pudiese borrar su tweet, apareciendo un botón de la siguiente forma:

Publicado por "usuario" a las "fecha de publicación"
Eliminar tweet
Contenido del tweet

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano, por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que intentó decir que tiene 2 tablas y no 2 base de datos , tal cuál está su código es erróneo por como emplea el `fetch` y la consulta no obtendrá el nombre del usuario al que corresponde el Tweet solo su id de acuerdo a su relación .

Teniendo la consulta correcta empleando `INNER JOIN` , se puede acceder al nombre de usuario que publico el `tweet`, además como no tiene parámetrizada la consulta no utilicé consultas preparadas en la respuesta , para saber si no hay filas puede comparar  `num_rows` del resultado que retorna `->query()`  si es `0` no hay resultados, caso contrario iteramos las filas con el `while` de siempre. *(el formato de presentación de los datos ya queda a su requerimiento)*

**Código**

```
$sqlTweets = "SELECT t.id, t.date, u.name as usuario
                FROM tweets t
                INNER JOIN usuarios u ON  t.userId = u.id";
if($sqlTweets  = $conn->query($sqlTweets)){
    if($sqlTweets->num_rows === 0)
    {
        echo "<br>"."<br>"."No hi ha tuits a mostrar!";
    }else{
         while($fila = $sqlTweets->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<h1>Publicado por " . $fila['usuario']. " a las " . $fila['date']. "";
            echo "<button>  Eliminar Tweet</button>";
        }
    }
}
```